# add condition to run the script only from my computer's IP in jmeter

Tags: javascript, jmeter

How can i add condition to run the script only from my computer's IP in jmeter ?
What i'm need to write in condition line at if controller ?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Below function gives you the ip of the computer in which you are running your script.

```
__machineIP
```

You need to use it like this.

```
${__machineIP}
```

For the below steup in the picture, any statements inside the if controller will get executed only if the ip of machine matches to the given ip "13.28.196.100".

[image]